# how to know from which device you are logged in

Tags: node.js, google-maps, azure

I just want to know from which device logged in our website and where from (Location)

I'm currently working on azure mobile service API

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, Azure mobile service APIs provided functions to approach resources on Azure but collect devices information.

If you want to detect device on website, I think [How to detect mobile device and get user agent info send and save that information to database on server, only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081346/how-to-detect-mobile-device-and-get-user-agent-info-send-and-save-that-informati) maybe the similar thread on SO.

And to get the location of mobile devices on Web apps, I think [How web apps ask location of mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701253/how-web-apps-ask-location-of-mobile-device) will be the similar thread.

If you are creating a mobile application, and a Azure Mobile Apps with node.js as a backend for your application. We can create a [custom API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-html-call-custom-api/), and hit the API to send device information and location when your user login the app. For different platform, there are built-in functions in their SDKs to collect devices information and location.